# Blender 2.79 does not detect GPU AMD RX580

Tags: gpu, linux, opencl

I've bought AMD RX580 recently and it seems Blender can't detect it, it has "none" in cycles compute device in system settings. I have ubuntu 18.04 installed, and already installed latest AMD linux driver from their site. Also installed ocl-icd-opencl-dev, but still blender does not detect my GPU. 
Here is the output of clinfo:

Number of platforms   0

:~$ dpkg --get-selections |grep opencl

libopencl1-amdgpu-pro:amd64     install

ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64        install

ocl-icd-opencl-dev:amd64        install

opencl-amdgpu-pro-icd           install

opencl-c-headers                install

What can I do to make blender detect my videocard?

UPD

Managed to get it working. What I did:
-Removed ocl-icd drivers
-Removed all amd drivers
-Rebooted and installed amd drivers with command line:
"./amdgpu-pro-install -y --opencl=legacy,pal" than rebooted again and now blender detects my videocard

Comment: I don't know much about OpenCL on Linux, but did you try everything on this page?  https://wiki.tiker.net/OpenCLHowTo